# Chemistry Precise

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What would be more precise to find the volume of a cube of metal and why?

1: Measuring cube with a ruler and calculating volume
2: Calculating the water displacement of the cube with a graduated cylinder
(1-2 Sentences)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how accurately performed is each measurement. One would have to take into account precision of ruler and asymmetry of cube, for example, in the first case, and adhesion of water to cube and cylinder, causing meniscus and other errors.

However, in some cases, ruler measurement would be **far** more accurate than water displacement: Archimedes would have shouted something other than "εὕρηκα" if he were measuring a cube of sodium (or congeners) in his bath. Doubt he'd want to lye in that!